# devexpressgrid filteration

Tags: devexpress, filtering, aspxgridview

i was trying to implement aspxgridview  with filteration.i have enabled the "Enable filteration" for the aspx gridview .
but when i try to type some letter in filter text box of the aspx grid view the whole data in the grid view gets disappears.
when i remove the letters in the filter text box of the aspxgridview ,still there is no records in the aspxgridview.

why is the records in the apsxgridview disappears  when the filteration occurs in aspxgridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are binding the grid to data at runtime.  If so, please try the solution from the [Why might paging (sorting, grouping, filtering) not work in the ASPxGridView?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/ViewKBIssue.aspx?kbid=K18183) article.  It should help.